# "this selection is not valid" error when using insert to reorder a column VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following *unsorted* tree:
[image: unsorted]

I have code that attempts to order it using a priority lookup in another sheet:

**Sorted:**
[image]

The code:

```
Sub SortWeights()

Dim formatRow As Integer        ' Current row in ordered list of parents
Dim weightRow As Integer        ' Current row while sorting weights
Dim startRow As Integer         ' First row in weights group
Dim endRow As Integer           ' Last row in weights group
Dim weightsSheet As Worksheet   ' Worksheet containing weights
Dim formatSheet As Worksheet    ' Worksheet containing ordered parent weights
Dim looking As Boolean          ' True while gathering child rows
Dim doShift As Boolean          ' True if weights group needs to be moved
Dim candidate As Range          ' Candidate weight
Dim sortingWeight As Range      ' Reformatted sorting weight name
Dim lastWeightRow As Integer

Const firstFormatRow As Integer = 1     'First row in ordered list of parents
Const lastFormatRow As Integer = 6      'Last row in ordered list of parents
Const firstWeightRow As Integer = 8     'First row in list of weights to be sorted
'Const lastWeightRow As Integer = 100      'Last row in list of weights to be sorted
Const weightNameColumn As Integer = 3   'Column with parent names to be sorted
Const formatNameColumn As Integer = 3   'Column with parent names in ascending order

Set weightsSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Weights")
Set formatSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Formatting")
formatRow = lastFormatRow
lastWeightRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
' Loop through the list of ordered parent weights
Do Until formatRow < firstFormatRow

    ' Reset everything
    looking = False
    doShift = False
    startRow = 0
    endRow = 0
    Set sortingWeight = formatSheet.Cells(formatRow, formatNameColumn)

    ' Loop through the list of all weights
    For weightRow = firstWeightRow To lastWeightRow

        Set candidate = weightsSheet.Cells(weightRow, weightNameColumn)

        ' If match found, start counting
        If candidate.Value = sortingWeight.Value Then
            ' If the match is in the first row, it is already in place, skip it.
            If weightRow = 1 Then
                Exit For
            Else
                startRow = weightRow
                looking = True
                doShift = True
            End If
        End If

        ' If gathering children...
        If looking Then
            ' If this is the last row, it is the end of the group.
            If weightRow = lastWeightRow Then
                endRow = weightRow
            ' Otherwise, if this is a new group, the previous row was the end.
            ElseIf candidate.IndentLevel = 2 And candidate <> sortingWeight Then
                endRow = weightRow - 1
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

    Next weightRow

    ' Only do the cut and insert if necessary
    If doShift Then
        weightsSheet.Range(CStr(startRow) & ":" & CStr(endRow)).Cut
        weightsSheet.Range(CStr(firstWeightRow) & ":" & CStr(firstWeightRow)).Insert
    End If

    ' Do the next parent.
    formatRow = formatRow - 1

Loop

End Sub
```

This code works fine on some trees, however occasionally, I will get a "this selection is not valid" error when running this on a slightly different tree. I can't seem to find what the issue is, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: `weightsSheet.Range(CStr(firstWeightRow) & ":" & CStr(firstWeightRow)).Insert`

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois Have you tried checking the values of `startRow` and `endRow` when you get this error?

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois would that get called like `Range(3:10).Insert`? If so it will fail. You need (I believe) `Range(3:10).EntireRow.Insert`

Comment: @dwirony No I have not, after adding a watch it seems like they are both empty, however I have no idea why.

Comment: @BruceWayne given the lack of values in startRow and endRow it seems like .EntireRow isn't the solution. It seems like the sort was working fine on other trees without that as well.

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois Somewhere along the way your boolean logic is not doing what you think it should be... I'd single out what line this is occurring on, then set a break point and step through using F8 and see where the assignment is missing.

Comment: I found a couple flaws in the Boolean logic; seems like my lastWeightRow should have been computed dynamically, and my last formatting row had to include all items.